# Can "fake rational surfaces" be simply-connected?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, fundamental-group

I say that a smooth projective complex algebraic surface $X$ is a "fake rational surface" if its Hodge diamond looks like:

[image]

and $X$ is of general type.

It is well-known that fake projective planes (the case $h^{1,1} = 1$) must be quotients of the holomorphic ball by a discrete group and hence must have $\pi_1(X)$ infinite.

Do examples of fake rational surfaces with $\pi_1(X) = 0$ or finite exist?

Comment: Yes. A famous one is the [Barlow surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barlow_surface). There have been other examples, notably by Lee and Park.

Comment: Thank you. If you make this an answer I will accept it.

Comment: OK, I put an answer, adding the references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been an open problem for a long time till R. Barlow gave an example (with $K^2=1$: Invent. Math. 79 (1985), no. 2, 293–301). Since then there have been other examples, first by Y. Lee and J. Park  (Invent. Math. 170 (2007), no. 3, 483–505), with $K^2=2$, then by H. Park, J. Park and D. Shin with $K^2=3$ and 4 (Geom. Topol. 13 (2009),   743–767 and 1483–1494.